# What ordering does dict.keys() and dict.values() guarantee?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-2.x

> This question arises from [this
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600844/4909087) where one user
>   uses `d.keys()` and `d.values()` separately to initialise a dataframe.

It's common knowledge that dictionaries in python versions under 3.6 are not ordered.

Consider a generic dictionary of the form:

```
d = {k1 : v1, k2 : v2, k3 : v3}
```

Where the keys `k*` are any hashable objects, and the values `v*` being any object. Of course, order cannot be guaranteed, but what about the order of `d.keys()` and `d.values()`?

**Python 2.x**

Both `d.keys()` and `d.values()` return lists. Say, `.keys()` returns `d`'s keys in the order `[k2, k1, k3]`. Is it now *always guaranteed* that `d.values()` returns the same relative ordering as `[v2, v1, v3]`? Furthermore, does the ordering remain the same no matter how many times these functions are called?

**Python 3.x (<3.6)**

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that `.keys` and `.values` do not guarantee any ordering at all here because they are set-like structures, thus having no order by definition and enabling you to perform set-like operations on them. But I'd still be interested to know if there is *any* sort of relative ordering between the two calls in this instance. **I'm guessing not.** I'd appreciate if someone could affirm or correct me.

Comment: In python 3.6+ (I think) there're ordered, the question is not whether you can use it,  but whether you should (I'm in the "you should" camp). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/1240268

Comment: Looks like `keys()` and `values()` come out in the same order. In python 2 it's arbitrary (but consistent) - but in python 3 it seems to be in definition order. Either way, it isn't a good idea to rely on this... There's no reason to, with `items()`.
Python 2 = https://repl.it/NwCu/0
Python 3 = https://repl.it/NwDC/0

Comment: @AndyHayden - the fact it's not guaranteed in the spec is by far the most overwhelming reason to not rely on it in my opinion :P They even say in the docs that it's an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely on...

Comment: I'm reeling at the fact that a [highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600844/4909087) has made some assumptions about ordering and nobody bat an eyelid.

Comment: @AndyHayden Another thing I find interesting is that, when passing dictionaries to `pd.DataFrame`, you almost always get a dataframe with columns in the same order as the keys.... astounded how that's always happened, with little to no exception.

Comment: @Shadow I'm with [Raymond Hettinger](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/850102884972675072). I also use f-strings everywhere now so everyone is forced to upgrade if they want to run my code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ as pointed out, in python 2 it was deterministic, early python 3 random, now it's insertion/written order. It'll be in the spec for sure, the behavior is so useful for kwargs etc. etc. I've seen the reliance in deterministic ordering in python 2 break (early) python 3 code - not fun.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That said, it turns out it always works for python 2.7 and python 3.6+. Provided you don't do anything silly like modify the dict mid iteration.

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks. I saw the [CPython implementation footnote here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), so I guess it's just best to never rely on any ordering.

Comment: Also the part after the footnote that mentions the items directly correspond with each other.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and for python 3 also https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects. Which is to say the answer you linked to isn't broken hmmm, it's still a little fishy - mainly as you want the .keys() and .values() calls to be close together. If there was somewhere to bet that it'd make it to the spec I would.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for what it's worth, I left a comment on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600844/3058609) pointing out this discussion and suggesting using `ks, vs = zip(*d.items())` instead.

Comment: @AndyHayden For `**kwargs` it is already in the spec, [starting from version 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/#specification). Still would not rely on dicts in general having that property.

Comment: It has **always** been the case that if you call `d.keys()` and `d.values()` in either order, with no intervening insertions or deletions, then corresponding items from those two sequences will be a correct (key, value) pair.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The general rules:

1. Before talking about what is guaranteed and what isn't, even if some ordering seems to be "guaranteed", it isn't.  You should not rely on it. It is considered bad practice, and could lead to nasty bugs.
2. `d.keys()`, `d.values()`, and `d.items()` all return the elements in a respective order.  The order should be treated as arbitrary (no assumptions should be made about it). ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items))
3. consecutive calls to `d.keys()`, `d.values()`, and `d.items()` are "stable", in the sense they are guaranteed to preserve the order of previous calls (assuming no insertion/deletion happens between the calls).
4. Since CPython's V3.6, [`dict` has been reimplemented](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict), and it now preserves *insertion* order.  This was not the goal of the change, but a side effect, and it is NOT part of the python spec, only a detail of the CPython implementation.  See point #1 above: relying on this is bad practice and should not be done.  Anyways, you should avoid writing CPython-specific code.
5. In Python2, order is deterministic (i.e. creating a dict twice in the same way will result with the same order).  In Python <3.6, it is no longer deterministic, so you can't rely on that either (I'm not sure if this non-determinism is part of the spec or just a CPython implementation detail).

EDIT: added point #5, thanks to @AndyHayden's comment.

Comment: Thanks, this reaffirms my suspicions. Do you have any sources you can draw from?

Comment: Especially part 3) about the stable ordering is very useful information that I didn't know about. So, to summarise, whether there is relative ordering or not, I shouldn't assume there is. Am I right?

Comment: For any future readers, see CPython implementation footnote [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), and the bit about guaranteed correspondence just below.

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't have a reference, but when you think about it, it is a direct result of point #2. If calling `keys()` and then `values()` preservers order, and calling `values()` and then `keys()` preserves order, it follows that calling `keys()` and then `keys`() preserves order.  It is easy to give a formal proof for that.

Comment: The non-determinism mentioned in point #5 is due to the non-determinism of the Python 3 `hash` function, which by default uses a random value to seed the hashes of str, bytes and datetime objects. You can set the PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable to a (machine) integer to make it deterministic. This is briefly mentioned in the command-line help, although that help claims that you need to set PYTHONHASHSEED to 'random' to invoke the random behaviour, that hasn't been true for several versions.

Comment: Note that this phenomenon also affects the ordering of sets. FWIW, the hash of a machine integer is just the integer itself, so sets of such integers, and dicts that use such integers for the keys, are deterministic.

Comment: Point #5 is rather misleading. The non-determinism in Python <3.6 doesn't come from the dict but from the strings (how they hash themselves), assuming that's what Andy showed. And you can have similarly non-deterministically hashing keys in Python2 as well. A good new point would be that Python ≥3.7 guarantees insertion order, it's not just a CPython implementation details anymore.