# Merging 3 datasets together

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 datasets (csv.) that I need to merge together inorder to make a motion chart. 
they all have countries as the columns and the year as rows.

The other two datasets look the same except one is population and the other is income. I've tried looking around to see what I can find to get the data set out like I'd like but cant seem to find anything.

I tried using pd.concat but it just lists it all one after the other not in separate columns.

merge all 3 data sets in preperation for making motionchart using pd.concat
`mc_data = pd.concat([df2, pop_data3, income_data3], sort = True)`

Any sort of help would be appreciated

EDIT: I have used the code as suggested, however I get a heap of NaN values that shouldn't be there

`mc_data = pd.concat([df2, pop_data3, income_data3], axis = 1, keys = ['df2', 'pop_data3', 'income_data3'])`

EDIT2: when I run .info and .index on them i get these results. Could it be to do with the data types? or the column entries?

[image: python output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600844):

You can do it with `concat` (the `keys` argument will create the hierarchical columns index):

```
pd.concat([df2, pop_data3, income_data3], axis=1, keys=['df2', 'pop_data3', 'income_data3'])
```

Comment: That has worked but I now have NaN values that shouldn't be there

Comment: This means that the dataset does not contain values for those years. e.g. `df2` does not have years 1970 -1974, `income_data3` doesn't have years 2011-2015.

Comment: It does though, when I view df2 before the merge it has values for every country for every year from 1970-2015

Comment: what does `df2.info()`, `df2.index`, `income_data3.info()`, `income_data3.index` print?

Comment: I have added a screen shot into the original question with the output, could it be the datatype affecting it? or the columns?

Comment: yes, `df2.index` shows a string index, convert it to int using `df2.index = df2.index.astype(int)`

Comment: That solved it thankyou!
I really appreciate your help